# Is it possible to open an "incognito" notebook?

Tags: evaluation, notebooks

In one notebook, I used package `X` to evaluate several very expensive expressions, let me call them `A`. Then I quit `X` and loaded package `Y` in order to evaluate several other very expensive expressions, let me call them `B`.

When evaluating `A`, I used `;` to hide one of the output since it's long (which is silly). But now I want to see the physical output of it, to do which I have to quit the kernal and reload package `X`.

Is there a way to re-evaluate `A` without quitting the kernal? Because I will use the output of `B` and don't want to re-evaluate all the expressions.

The idea sounds like an "incognito tab" in google chrome, and I hope in that "incognito tab", revaluation of `A` will have no impact on `B`.

This may sound weird, but any ideas?

Comment: Under the `Evaluation` menu list, chose `Kernel Configuration Options …` and create a new kernel name.  Then, open notebook A, and under the `Evaluation` menu list, choose `Notebook's Kernel` to assign the new kernel name to the kernel.  This works, provided that your Mathematica license allows enough kernels.

Comment: Could you provide a schematic code to show those steps? Otherwise it may be tough to answer.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks for your comments, this actually solved my question. I can do it without any problems. But I don't know how to adopt your answer since it's in a comment form. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Kuba I can't share my code as the packages I mentioned in the post are from my colleagues which are not public yet. But bbgodrey's comment above actually solved my question, and thank you all the same.

Comment: @Y.Du  It is my pleasure to be of assistance.  Best wishes.

Comment: Another option that I occasionally use is to use a lower version of Mathematica, as they are separate entities. So I currently have v11 and v11.2  both installed, so if both of my kernels are in use I open v11 to run something quick.

Comment: @KraZug: it is also possible to run two instances of the same version at the same time (again might depend on your license, the standard license allows two frontend processes). So you can but don't have to use different versions.

Comment: @AlbertRetey, when I open Mathematica 11.2 from the start menu it combines it with the other notebooks that I have open in v11.2.

Comment: Which OS are you on? What exactly do you do when you "open from the start menu"?

Comment: @KraZug That's also a good idea, thank you :)

Comment: @AlbertRetey From google search, it seems that to run multiple instances, you basically need to do exactly what bbgodfrey has suggested above. Or, do you have different options?

Comment: @AlbertRetey, I'm on Windows 7. When I open a .nb file it opens as a window within the main Mathematica tab (if that makes sense)

Comment: OK, that is the expected behavior. I'm on windows 10 so the details might be slightly different. To start another instance, you should be able to use the start menu, search the mathematica entry of your choice and click on it to open the second instance. You could also use the command line or a right click on a mathematica symbol in the quickstart menu...